# Detect mouse released in Unity new input system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, io

I am using the new input system but I cannot seem to get the mouse clicks to behave correctly.

Im trying to implement an attack with the left mouse button. I created the action and it is firing, but the value never turns back to false.

```
        public void OnSprint(InputValue value)
        {
            SprintInput(value.isPressed);
        }

        public void OnAttack(InputValue value)
        {
            AttackInput(value.isPressed);
        }
```

Why is the sprint working normally, when pressed it goes to true, and when released it fires a new event saying the value is false.

However the mouse attack only returns true and then never goes back to false. There is no event fired when I release the left mouse button.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the `Action Type` from `Button` to `Pass Through` and now it is firing true when mouse is pressed and false when released.

[image: Action type pass through]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to AttackInput(value.isReleased), and change it so it fires when false.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The new input system is event driven/focused, unlike the old Input class.

Hook into the `canceled` event of the input.

```
inputs.Attack.canceled += (ctx) => StopAttacking();
```